# Binding works only one time

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, mvvm, xceed

I binded the SelectedItem of a CheckComboBox to an ObservableCollection. 
When I choose items for the first time, it works well.
After the first time, when I choose items again, it doesn't work again.
 The ViewModelCode:

```
public ObservableCollection<Object> SelectedFirmwares
{
    get 
    {
      return _selectedFirmwares;                
    }
}
```

The XML code:

```
<xctk:CheckComboBox x:Name="FirmwareType" 
                    IsSelectAllActive="True"
                    IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                    Width="92"
                    Margin="-480,58,-310,0.4"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Firmware, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="{Binding ItemsSource}"
                    SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding SelectedFirmwares}" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend your property with an setter

```
public ObservableCollection<Object> SelectedFirmwares
{
    get 
    {
      return _selectedFirmwares;                
    }
    set
    {
      if (object.Equals(value, selectedFirmwares))
          return;

      _selectedFirmwares = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

And change your binding to a `TwoWay` binding

```
SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding SelectedFirmwares, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
```